# when is the regid in GCM checked?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, registry, google-cloud-messaging, reboot

I am researching when the regId in GCM is checked.

I wonder whether it is checked whenever the application starts new(after rebooting the device) or just checked once when the app starts first on the device.

I think it should be checked whenever the app starts because the regId could be refreshed by the policy of google GCM server .

is it right?

Comment: I find that the regId changes whenever my app changes, e.g. when the app is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right, when ever app starts an Unique registration Id is received and you need to store it in your server.